# Execute a query and get own pid

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam, mariadb

Is there any way in MySQL to launch a query and get the PID from it?
This could be usefull to get metadata while the query is being executed.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of metadata do you think you could get with the PID?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: You could execute `show processlist` on another connection. MySQL is synchronous, so you can't do anything on the connection with the query while the query is going.

Comment: Right, but how do I know which query is the one I want if there are 200 queries running at the same time? I need to get the PID to filter my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`CONNECTION_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT CONNECTION_ID() AS pid;
```

Comment: That should work. Thanks. BTW: there is a typo in the command.